# Gem install error (gem install sass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using my root account for terminal:
I installed ruby (yum install ruby), and when tryng to install sass or other gems it gives me this error:

```
[root@ve555 /]# ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p598 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
[root@ve555 /]# gem install sass
Successfully installed sass-3.4.22
/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- json/pure (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:60:in `rescue in <module:JSON>'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:57:in `<module:JSON>'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/json-1.7.7/lib/json.rb:54:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/text.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/code_object.rb:28:in `<class:CodeObject>'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/code_object.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/generator/markup.rb:59:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/generator/darkfish.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/rdoc.rb:563:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:64:in `load_rdoc'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:229:in `setup'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:142:in `generate'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:54:in `block in generation_hook'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:53:in `each'
        from /usr/share/gems/gems/rdoc-4.0.0/lib/rdoc/rubygems_hook.rb:53:in `generation_hook'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/request_set.rb:189:in `call'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/request_set.rb:189:in `block in install'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/request_set.rb:188:in `each'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/request_set.rb:188:in `install'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:205:in `install_gem'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:255:in `block in install_gems'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in `each'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:251:in `install_gems'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/commands/install_command.rb:158:in `execute'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/command.rb:310:in `invoke_with_build_args'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/command_manager.rb:169:in `process_args'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/command_manager.rb:139:in `run'
        from /usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:55:in `run'
        from /usr/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

Can someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `gem install json_pure` before `gem install sass` ?
(This supposed to be in comment section, but my reputation is insufficient)